# Unstructured (Adlib) XML to structured XML using XSLT, grouping similar nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got an unstructured Adlib XML file, which contains data in the following format :

```
<record>
    ...
    <dimension.type>height</dimension.type>
    <dimension.type>width</dimension.type>
    <dimension.type>height</dimension.type>
    <dimension.type>width</dimension.type>
    <dimension.type>depth</dimension.type>
    <dimension.notes>without frame</dimension.notes>
    <dimension.notes>without frame</dimension.notes>
    <dimension.notes>with frame</dimension.notes>
    <dimension.notes>with frame</dimension.notes>
    <dimension.notes>with frame</dimension.notes>
    <dimension.value>28.0</dimension.value>
    <dimension.value>47.9</dimension.value>
    <dimension.value>41.4</dimension.value>
    <dimension.value>62.9</dimension.value>
    <dimension.value>8.0</dimension.value>
    ...
</record>
```

What I would like to do is transform this to the following format :

```
<record>
    ...
    <dimension>
       <notes>without frame</notes>
       <height>28.0</height>
       <width>47.9</width>
    </dimension>
    <dimension>
       <notes>with frame</notes>
       <height>41.4</height>
       <width>62.9</width>
       <depth>8.0</depth>
    </dimension>
    ...
</record>
```

However I'm kind of stuck, since these nodes refer to information in other nodes at the same position. I did come up with the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="dimension.value">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
  <dimension>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="../dimension.type[$pos] = 'height'">
      <height><xsl:value-of select="."/></height>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="../dimension.type[$pos] = 'width'">
      <width><xsl:value-of select="."/></width>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="../dimension.type[$pos] = 'depth'">
      <depth><xsl:value-of select="."/></depth>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
  <notes>
    <xsl:value-of select="../dimension.notes[$pos]"/>
  </notes>
  </dimension>
</xsl:template>
```

Which produces data in the format :

```
<dimension>
   <height>28.0</height>
   <notes>without frame</notes>
</dimension>
<dimension>
    <width>47.9</width>
    <notes>without frame</notes>
</dimension>
<dimension>
    <height>41.4</height>
    <notes>with frame</notes>
</dimension>
<dimension>
    <width>62.9</width>
    <notes>with frame</notes>
</dimension>
<dimension>
    <depth>8.0</depth>
    <notes>with frame</notes>
</dimension>
```

But that doesn't do the grouping on note part, which would make processing the result a bit easier (now I solve this in code, but there has to be a way for XSLT to do it, right?). Any help (pointers to relevant information or relevant XSLT snippets) would be greatly appreciated...

BTW I translated parts of the XML/XSLT to make it easier to understand, the when:test actually checks for Dutch descriptions and transforms them into the equivalent English tags...

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0 which has a powerful `xsl:for-each-group` construct?

Comment: Not at the moment, no, since PHP (which I use to process the files) still relies on XSLT 1.0... Adding Java/Saxon into the mix to process the XML files would be overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="dimension.notes[1]" mode="group"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dimension.notes" mode="group">
    <dimension>
      <notes>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </notes>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </dimension>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::dimension.notes[not(. = current())][1]" mode="group"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dimension.notes">
    <xsl:variable name="pos">
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../dimension.type[position() = $pos]">
      <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::dimension.notes[1][. = current()]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dimension.type">
    <xsl:param name="pos"/>
    <xsl:element name="{.}">
      <xsl:value-of select="../dimension.value[position() = $pos]"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to do the trick! XSLT is not really my area of expertise, it's been a few years since I last had to use it - guess I'd better invest some time in it :p.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example using XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="dimension.notes" group-adjacent=".">
        <dimension>
          <notes>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
          </notes>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </dimension>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dimension.notes">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../dimension.type[position() eq $pos]">
      <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dimension.type">
    <xsl:param name="pos"/>
    <xsl:element name="{.}">
      <xsl:value-of select="../dimension.value[position() eq $pos]"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not sure it solves your problem as the "..." in your sample might require more complex coding, depending on what kind of elements exactly can occur there and what you want to do with them.